# Issues getting a Rich Text Field working in React - using react-rte but open to suggestions

Tags: reactjs, forms, rtf, formik, rich-text-editor

I'm trying to do something simple (it all starts out that way anyway...)

rich text field in a form, that works with validation and errors, its Formik/React. pretty straight forward.

I did some research on RT Editors.

TinyMCE - requires an API key. I dont want to worry about API issues and keys, this is an RTF, loets not complicate it that much. also i dont like their branding on my field.

CKEditor - 1MB after build, by far my projects biggest package and i have a lot of stuff running. This seems like great docs tho. some of the smaller ones are not as well documented.

draftJS - FB made, so should work great w react right... 500K package, looks about as small as can be for a RTF. not super intuitive.

react-rte, mod of draftJS, super easy install and UI, but hooking it up s a black box and no documentation...

Here is my react-rte code
keep in mind the component is RichTextEdit, the dependency is RichTextEditor

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import RichTextEditor from "react-rte";
 
class RichTextEdit extends Component {
 
  state = {
    value: RichTextEditor.createEmptyValue(),
  }
 
  onChange = (value) => {
    this.setState({value});
    if (this.props.onChange) {
      this.props.onChange(
        value.toString("html"),
      );
    }
  };
 
  render () {

    const toolbarConfig = {
      display: ["INLINE_STYLE_BUTTONS", "BLOCK_TYPE_BUTTONS", "BLOCK_TYPE_DROPDOWN", "HISTORY_BUTTONS"],
      INLINE_STYLE_BUTTONS: [
        {label: "Bold", style: "BOLD"},
        {label: "Italic", style: "ITALIC"},
        {label: "Underline", style: "UNDERLINE"},
      ],
      BLOCK_TYPE_DROPDOWN: [
        {label: "Normal", style: "unstyled"},
        {label: "Heading Large", style: "header-one"},
        {label: "Heading Medium", style: "header-two"},
        {label: "Heading Small", style: "header-three"},
      ],
      BLOCK_TYPE_BUTTONS: [
        {label: "UL", style: "unordered-list-item"},
        {label: "OL", style: "ordered-list-item"},
      ],
    };

    return (
      <Box width={2/3}>
        <RichTextEditor
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          toolbarConfig={toolbarConfig}
        />
      </Box>
    );
  }
}

export default RichTextEdit;
```

heres my error

```
onloadwff.js:71 Assertion failed: Input argument is not an HTMLInputElement
```

need to get this field to spit out a value somehow, does anyone have suggestions?

I've checked out docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-rte
there's not much there

any other simple implementations of a rtf into a form?

Answer (score 1):

this error comes from lastpass plugin and is probably something we can ignore